# not display the button in jSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I want to hide and show the table row based on a condition.
The id of my atable row is showhide2.

This is my part of code to use show/hide the row

```
<%if(group.equals("Y")){%>
                         <input<% try{if(dTO.getStat() == 0){%> style="display:none;" <%}}catch(Exception ex){} %> type="button" value="View" id="btnview" name="btnview"   onclick="statusChange('view', 'add_userFrm');hide_menu('showhide2');loadDataForGivenDiv('add_userFrm');" class="button" style="width:100px"/>
                        <%}else{ %><input<% try{if(dTO.getStat() == 0){%> style="display:none;" <%}}catch(Exception ex){} %> type="button" value="View" id="btnview" name="btnview" onclick="statusChange('view', 'add_userFrm');show_menu('showhide2');loadDataForGivenDiv('add_userFrm');" class="button" style="width:100px"/>
                         <%}%>
```

But the button "View" not shows in  my application.I cant solve this.

This is the function used to hide the row

```
function hide_menu(id){
                            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById(id).style.width = "0";

                        }
```

I guess problem is in my code which has the button "View"

Comment: If you want to focus on the javascript try doing a view source on the page as it is rendered in the browser. That way it is easier to see the html and javascript as the nrowser sees it. Also use a tool like firebug to view the execution of the javascript on the page.

Answer (score 0):

In both if and else you set display to none, could that be it?

Comment: i have removed display of none and checked.but still the View button is not showing.

Comment: Have you tried Vincents tip from above and view the rendered source in the web browser? To see if the input are there or if the group is Y.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding any character in front of the input tag

e.g.

```
<%if(group.equals("Y")){%>
                     a<input<% try{if(dTO.getStat() == 0){%> style="display:none;"      <%}}catch(Exception ex){} %> type="button" value="View" id="btnview" name="btnview"   onclick="statusChange('view', 'add_userFrm');hide_menu('showhide2');loadDataForGivenDiv('add_userFrm');" class="button" style="width:100px"/>
```

If the 'a' does not show then

```
if(group.equals("Y"))
```

is probably always false

Answer (score -1):

From the initial 
This is my part of code to use show/hide the row

> style="display:none;"  type="button" value="View" id="btnview" name="btnview"   onclick="statusChange('view', 'add_userFrm');hide_menu('showhide2');loadDataForGivenDiv('add_userFrm');" class="button" style="width:100px"/>
>                            style="display:none;"  type="button" value="View" id="btnview" name="btnview" onclick="statusChange('view', 'add_userFrm');show_menu('showhide2');loadDataForGivenDiv('add_userFrm');" class="button" style="width:100px"/>
>
> But the button "View" not shows in my application.I cant solve this.

The if(dTO.getStat() == 0){%> style="display:none;" ><%} as Anders remarked, you're probably forgetting

```
   if(dTO.getStat() == 0){%> style="display:none;" ><%} else {%> style="display: inline;"><%}
```

?